# wp_enqueue_style don't register all google fonts

Tags: plugin-development

I created this class below and I retrieved all google font names from google web font API URL. but in `wp_enqueue_style` function only return the first google font name called `ABeeZee` and don't return other font names

the URL `wp_enqueue_style` returned in my theme is like this `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=ABeeZee`

why the `$font_list` array only return first array value in `wp_enqueue_style`? Does I have an error in my foreach loop?

```
<?php
    class YPE_Bsn_Gfonts {
    static function YPE_bsgooglefonts() {
        $google_api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyDAbNqy_aYo7Tua3S4s7-I9SRZl_C8xdqo';
        $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get($google_api_url, array('sslverify' => false )));
        if( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {

        } else {
        $data = json_decode($response, true);
        $items = $data['items'];
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $font_list[] .= str_replace(' ', '+', $item['family']);
        }
    }
    return $font_list;
}
static function YPE_bsregister_google_fonts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='.YPE_Bsn_Gfonts::YPE_bsgooglefonts().'', false );
}
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array('YPE_Bsn_Gfonts','YPE_bsregister_google_fonts'));
?>
```

Comment: if you get the expected resunl from `wp_remote_get then it is probably some simple php error ;)

Comment: @Mark Kaplun if you can help me and correct my code

Comment: you need to put var dumps everywhere, it is impossible to remotely debug someone else's code.

Comment: but when i use echo $item['family']  within foreach loop print all font families name why don't print theme within wp_enqueue_style

Comment: you have a `.=` in your assigment that I don't know what should be the result of it, otherwise as I said you need to debug it, impossible to help remotely if there is nothing very obvious

Comment: $item['family'] array contains all google font names (808 font names) it is work correctly when printing it within foreach loop. I want to put all font names into the end of google font url URL like this https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=$item['family']. but when i put the $item['family'] also show first font name and don't show others font name. if you can modify my code until can put all font names to end of url

Comment: You want to load 808 fonts, at the same time? Did I understand that correctly? That's a bad idea.

Comment: what is the best idea for select google fonts from admin panel i want user can change font family of each part from admin panel what is the best idea for this